# Can you add a map to Trello and have the card render the map image?

Tags: trello

I'd like to be able to add a Google or Bing map (complete with image) to the back of a Trello card.  I know I can do hyperlinks or even markdown in the card description, but I'd prefer something that operates the way YouTube integration works.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't currently possible, consider contacting Trello to get it on the development board https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c